# Matlab: convert array of number to array of strings, with formatting

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, type-conversion

I would like to convert a numeric array like this:

```
[12.3134 25.3234 34.4190 466.6765 55.5454]
```

Into a cell array of strings, with a single digit after the decimal point like this:

```
'12.3' '25.3' '34.6' '466.6' '55.5'
```

This `arrayfun` gets me close, but I can't figure out how to add the format spec to the `num2str` function.

```
arrayfun(@num2str, A, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass inputs to anonymous functions:

```
A = [12.3134 25.3234 34.4190 466.6765 55.5454];
B = arrayfun(@(x)num2str(x, '%.1f'), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Which returns:

```
B =

  1×5 cell array

    '12.3'    '25.3'    '34.4'    '466.7'    '55.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in 16b you can do

```
>> A = [12.3134 25.3234 34.4190 466.6765 55.5454];
>> B = compose('%.1f',A)

B = 

  1×5 string array

    "12.3"    "25.3"    "34.4"    "466.7"    "55.5"
```